# Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment won't show

Tags: java, android

I created a `Modal Bottom Sheet` fragment and by default has these lines

```
/**
* <p>A fragment that shows a list of items as a modal bottom sheet.</p>
* <p>You can show this modal bottom sheet from your activity like this:</p>
* <pre>
* ShoppingCartListDialogFragment.newInstance(30).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
* </pre>
* <p>You activity (or fragment) needs to implement {@link ShoppingCartListDialogFragment.Listener}.</p>
*/
```

Then on my `MainActivity.java` i have an `onClick` function like this:

```
public void showShoppingCart(View view) {
    // Testing
    ShoppingCartListDialogFragment.newInstance(30).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Whenever i click the button my app crashes i get an error from the fragment's `onAttach` method

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
    if (parent != null) {
        mListener = (Listener) parent;
    } else {
        mListener = (Listener) context; <-- Error on this line
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what am i missing here? I really don't get the last comment line. Where do i implement a `.Listener` ?

Error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.johng.assosfood, PID: 28856
              java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.johng.assosfood.ProductsActivity cannot be cast to com.example.johng.assosfood.ShoppingCartListDialogFragment$Listener
                  at com.example.johng.assosfood.ShoppingCartListDialogFragment.onAttach(ShoppingCartListDialogFragment.java:59)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1367)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1754)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1822)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2591)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2378)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2333)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2240)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I set up a listener for the fragments, my onAttach() usually looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof yourFragmentListener) {
        mListener = (yourFragmentListener) context;
    } else {
        // Error Code
    }
}
```

This way it only casts if the activity it attaches to is implementing its listener. If you are getting the error code, you are likely not implementing your fragment's listener in your MainActivity. Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ShoppingCartListDialog.Listener {
// If it successfully implements, (you have all the methods
//defined in this class) then it is an instance of the listener
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you

Comment: But how can i get Listener inside Fragment